# How to modify the "Issues" collection in the GetBuildDetails response in TFS 2017

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task, vnext

We are building a custom Visual Studio build task to implement compliance validation of the builds defined by our developper teams.

The objective is to mark builds using "unauthorized" tasks, or failing to use mandatory tasks in a way that will be possible for a BuildCompleted servicehook to act upon later on.

We are creating a JSON structure describing the different business rules we want to enforce, and we have a service hook catching end-of-build events to create a tracability file that will mark the build artifacts as "deployable" or not.

I can see from the MS references that a Issue collection is returned with the GetBuildDetails responss that seems to list exactly the kind of information we'd like to pass along.

Anyone found a way to populate that property?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want add additional information to the request body of webbooks request? If so, how about add it to the build result by using  Logging Commands? (e.g.  ##vso[task.logissue]error/warning message) https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Comment: That seems exactly what we were looking for; I'll get back to you tomorrow when we try it out.  thanks!

Comment: Feel free to post the result here. If it solves your issue, I will post an answer.

Comment: What's the result now?

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I confirm it worked as intented.  Please make it a reply and I'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is add additional information to the build result by using [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) (e.g. `##vso[task.logissue]error/warning message`)